# What is the best way to assign different default content filters to different user roles in Drupal 5

Tags: drupal

The situation is this: I want one user group to have one filter as default on blogs, while another group - another filter, without having an effect on filter defaults for other content types.  I know there are a few modules for this, but how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Default Filter](http://drupal.org/project/default_filter) module --- I think this should do what you want.  It allows setting the default content filter per role per content type, and allows weighting each default (so one default outranks another if the user has multiple roles).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the [Filter Default](http://drupal.org/project/filter_default) module, but they are pointing users to [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module if you are on Drupal 6.

So if you are on Drupal 6 go with [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats). Drupal 5 use [Filter Default](http://drupal.org/project/filter_default)

-Ed